# how do I get the Id of elements having a same class?

Tags: jquery, html

i have a class `.myclass` i want to get the id of all textbox [html] who have this class.

how  i can do this.

i need to do this in jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
var ids = $('.class').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X3Nd7/

It works best if you are sure that all elements have an ID attribute. If not, the array will contain `undefined` entries.

Reference: [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    var id = [];
    $('.myclass').each(function () {
        if (this.id) {
            id.push(this.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.someClass').each(function(){ // <-- This is a cycle, where we go through all elements having class="someClass"
    $(this).attr('id'); // <-- This contains id of a current element (in the cycle)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".myclass :text").each( function() { alert($(this).attr('id')); });
```

You may also want to consult the documentation at
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/